# How can we call same listener method for different elements of the view in extjs?

Tags: extjs

I have a view from which an event is fired and gets listen in its controller.
How can we call the same listener for multiple elements in the view.

If I add same itemId to both the buttons, only the last one gets renderer. So, just for reference I have given the same id in the sample code here.

I want to call "showPopup" when clicked on both the buttons with ofcourse, different parameters.

View:

```
{
    xtype : 'container',
    layout : 'hbox',
    items : [ {
        xtype : 'datefield',
        fieldLabel : 'Date 1',
    },
        {
            xtype : 'button',
            itemId: 'myPopup',
            listeners : {
                click : function() {
                    this.fireEvent('displayPopup', 'abc','def')
                }
            }
        },
        {
            xtype : 'datefield',
            fieldLabel : 'Date 2',
        },
        {
            xtype : 'button',
            itemId: 'myPopup',
            listeners : {
                click : function() {
                     this.fireEvent('displayPopup', 'xyz','lmn')
                }
            }
        } ]
},
```

Controller:

```
listen : {
        component : {
            'myPopup'' : {
                displayPopup : 'showPopup'
            }
        }
    },

    showPopup: function(param1, param2){
    //my code
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you may have noticed itemIds are unique (because of this, only the last one is being rendered), as you controller is set to listen to a specific component itemId, in your case, it will only fire in your last component, my solution is to not listen to a specific component, but just call the controller function from your button click event.

Controller:

```
Ext.define('MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.MyController',
    displayPopup: function(param1, param2) {
        console.log(`param1: ${param1}`);
        console.log(`param2: ${param2}`);

    }
});
```

View:

```
{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'hbox',
    controller: 'MyController', //set the controller
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Date 1',
          }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        listeners: {
            click: function() {
                //get ref of controller and call its function
                this.up('container').getController().displayPopup('abc', 'def')
            }
        }
          }, {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Date 2',
          }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        listeners: {
            click: function() {
                //get ref of controller and call its function
                this.up('container').getController().displayPopup('xyz', 'lmn')
            }
        }
   }]
}
```

Like this, you won't need any itemdIds at all.

If you still want to listen to a specific component from your controller you can use component queries

```
listen: {
    component: {
        'container[itemId=MyContainer] button': {
            //listen to displayPopup from all buttons inside a container with itemId = MyContainer
            displayPopup: function(param1, param2) {
                console.log(`fired from controller listen, param1=${param1}, param2=${param2}`);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2u4s)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to avoid using itemIds if you can. Just like you wouldn't rely on adding Ids to everything if you were writing vanilla JS the same should apply here.

Instead you should do the follow:

- Call a controller method from the button listener

  - Instead of defining a `listener` we should use `handler` as this will support accessibility and keyboard inputs.
- Define custom properties `customProp` on your button
- Handle the custom properties in your controller method.

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    requires: [
        'Fiddle.view.main.MainModel',
        'Fiddle.view.main.MainController'
    ],
    viewModel: {
        type: 'main'
    },
    controller: 'main',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Date 1',
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'button 1',
        customProp: 'custom-prop-1',
        handler: 'handleButtonClick'
    }, {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Date 2',
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'button 2',
        customProp: 'custom-prop-2',
        handler: 'handleButtonClick'
    }]
});
```

And then in your controller

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.main.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.main',
    handleButtonClick: function(button){
        var customProp = button.customProp;
    }
});
```